# Is it possible to disable / enable Mobile Data from an app or a widget?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to disable / enable Mobile Data from an app or a widget using a simple switch button.

The goal here is to reproduce the same path from an custom app / widget than:

> Settings > Mobile Data > Mobile Data with turn on / turn off switch
>   button.

Is there is solutions to do that?

Comment: It seems like the router would have to do that as you can't remotely control an iPhone like that and you can't monitor an iPhones total bandwidth from within an app

Comment: You can en-/disable mobile data via Siri. Isn't that an option?

Comment: Ok, so I will have to make it manually. It's understandable and that make sense, yes. Thank you @Jack.

Comment: Yes it is, thank you for your suggestion @vadian. I was asking because when I'm in subway, It's boring for me to doing this path manually and was looking for the lazy option to retrieve my 4g more faster without turn on Plane Mode because I'm using a headphone in bluetooth and this one is also disabled when I doing that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible. On iOS you don't have access to system settings unless your device is jailbroken.

Comment: I was wondering myself if it was possible, thank you very much for your confirmation @Sulthan.